# How to find where is the filter being added?

Tags: wordpress

I am using Bethlehem Theme in wordpress, in the footer, there's a section "Connect with us", with a facebook icon below, however the icon was not shown properly.

[print screen: Social Icon not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO3gq.png)

[print screen: footer code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABMFx.png)

[print screen: Already checked the "Connect With us" is not generated from Appearance -> footer widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n4QW.png)

I already updated the code, however the updated facebook icon not shown:

```
function bethlehem_social_icons() {
$social_icons_args = apply_filters( 'bethlehem_social_icons_args', array(
array(
            'id'        => 'facebook',
            'title'     => __( 'Facebook', 'bethlehem' ),
            'class'     => 'hb-fb',
            'icon'      => 'fab fa-facebook-square',
            'link'      => '#'
        ),
        array(
            'id'        => 'twitter',
            'title'     => __( 'Twitter', 'bethlehem' ),
            'class'     => 'hb-tw',
            'icon'      => 'fab fa-twitter',
            'link'      => '#'
        ),
        array(
            'id'        => 'google-plus',
            'title'     => __( 'Google Plus', 'bethlehem' ),
            'class'     => 'hb-google-plus',
            'icon'      => 'fab fa-google-plus-g',
            'link'      => '#'
        ),
    ) );
etc.....
```

I would like to know where is "bethlehem_social_icons_args", I am thinking my new "fab fa-facebook-square" not being applied after filters applied, can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would asvise to always look through the theme documentaion first. Usually you can edit footer widgets under `Appearance > Widgets > Footer Widgets`.

You can check the screenshot [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/RcMhP95uvJ) (sorry for the non-english language).

Comment: The footer Widgets didn't got this. The code i want to edit appears before the Footer Widgets.